# Python (pip) package installation fails with 'fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory'

Tags: python, gcc, g++, pip

When I try to install a certain python package (hunspell), it fails with the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61:
fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what to do to correct this?

I am on a fresh Linux Mint 18 'Sarah' install.

Answer (score 11):

Someone on another forum suggested updating the g++ compiler with

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

and then relaunching the pip installation

I'm not sure what exactly was the problem, but it worked!
If anyone can explain what is going on here, please do so in the comments.

Comment: After I install g++ package, and then run 'pip install paramiko' I got this error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/_openssl.c:434:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory.

So I follow this post: https://amp.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5gvadg/unable_to_download_the_cryptography_library/ 
And run this command: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: Something similar, but on mac os x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877659/fatal-error-limits-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: This worked for me when I was installing twisted. Before trying this I had also upped the required version of zope.interface to 5.0.0 as per this answer to a different question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991816/364088 .