# Python Dependency satisfied but pip still complains for zope.interface==4.6.0

Tags: python-3.x, pip

While installing all the packages, I am getting no matching version error for `zope.interface` package even though the version is present in the list.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement zope.interface==4.6.0 (from versions: 3.3.0b1, 3.3.0b2, 3.3.0, 3.3.0.1, 3.4.0b1, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.2, 3.5.3, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.2, 3.6.3, 3.6.4, 3.6.5, 3.6.6, 3.6.7, 3.6.8, 3.7.0, 3.8.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2, 4.3.3, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.2.0, 5.3.0a1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0).
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for zope.interface==4.6.0

As seen above the version *to-be-installed* is present in the *from-versions* list but pip still complains and errors out.
What is going wrong here ?
I am on Python 3.9.5 with pip 21.1.1

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved a similar thing.  You didn't paste this as part of your error message, so we may be different, but just in case:

The causative issue for me here was related to setup tools.  Specifically, in the error output, I got an error ending with `ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature' from 'setuptools'`.

It appears that `zope.interface<5.0.0` relies on a deprecated API from `setuptools`, so pip throws away the matching distribution once it errors out.  Pinning `setuptools` to version 45, or using `zope.interface==5.0.0` or later, should resolve this.

See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017.