# Error while installing featuretools on mac

Tags: python, macos, gcc, pip, featuretools

System specification:

MacOS Mojava

Version:10.14.1 (18B75)

I am trying to install  `featuretools` on mac using pip.

Featuretools is a python library used to generate new set of features using the existing features.

command used:  `python -m pip install featuretools`

But I'm getting this error:

```
 error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Failed building wheel for psutil
  Running setup.py clean for psutil
Failed to build psutil
Installing collected packages: psutil, distributed, featuretools
  Found existing installation: psutil 5.4.5
    Uninstalling psutil-5.4.5:
      Successfully uninstalled psutil-5.4.5
  Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-tpipbc01/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-record-xb78kya7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memory_leaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_osx' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/arch
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/arch/osx
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=548 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    In file included from /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                     from /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                     from /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include/python3.6m/Python.h:11,
                     from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
     #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of psutil
Command "/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-tpipbc01/psutil/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-record-xb78kya7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-tpipbc01/psutil/
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error??

Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877659/fatal-error-limits-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error%3A+limits.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: try running `xcode-select --install` from the terminal as described in the links by phd

Comment: @MaxKanter Thanks but I have already tried this....and it is still not working..

Comment: Had the same error on OSX 10 and can confirm that `xcode-select --install` and then installing `featuretools` solved the problem.