# Problem with installation of bintrees package

Tags: python

**EDIT:** question solved by [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509602/cant-compile-c-program-on-a-mac-after-upgrade-to-mojave)

My question is not about xcode problem because after I have typed:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then i have recieved

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

When I run the following code in my terminal:

```
pip install bintrees
```

to install bintrees package then I receive the following error message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: bintrees
  Building wheel for bintrees (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yg/k7bblhjs4sj89bl6b5ygcjrw0000gn/T/pip-install-hhqgwgcf/bintrees/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/yg/k7bblhjs4sj89bl6b5ygcjrw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-_s_pguci --python-tag cp36:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/treeslice.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/rbtree.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/avltree.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/bintree.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  copying bintrees/abctree.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  running build_ext
```

(...)

```
  skipping 'bintrees/cython_trees.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'bintrees.cython_trees' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c bintrees/ctrees.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/bintrees/ctrees.o
  In file included from /anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                   from /anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                   from /anaconda3/include/python3.6m/Python.h:11,
                   from bintrees/ctrees.h:12,
                   from bintrees/ctrees.c:9:
  /anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2/4.8.5/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
   #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                               ^

 compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for bintrees
  Running setup.py clean for bintrees
Failed to build bintrees
Installing collected packages: bintrees
  Running setup.py install for bintrees ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yg/k7bblhjs4sj89bl6b5ygcjrw0000gn/T/pip-install-hhqgwgcf/bintrees/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/yg/k7bblhjs4sj89bl6b5ygcjrw0000gn/T/pip-record-gk8f7gsy/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
```

My question is how to install this particular library? Why do I have this error? How to fix this?

Error message is much longer however I have posted only a snippet here - stackoverflow does not allow for posting with such a huge amounts of code.

Comment: I think you just missed the most important lines in compilation. Would mind pasting the last few lines above "compilation terminated"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877659/fatal-error-limits-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: No it is not `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: @knh190 you were right it was the problem but the problem was different